# Single-swf preloader wrapper in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

I have a .swf that I'd like to create a preloader for. In the end, I want a single file which combines both the preloader and the content .swf.

Every tutorial I can find on Flash preloaders offers one of two options:

1. Using a URLRequest in the preloader wrapper to load an external content .swf. This will not work because I do not want two .swfs.
2. A "single-swf" solution like [this one](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/699675) which works for assets which you have created in the Flash IDE. I assumed I would easily be able to go this route, but I'm having trouble. I cannot use the Flash IDE to import my content .swf. I can use an embed tag like so:

   ```
   [Embed(source="content.swf")]
   private var MyContent:Class;
   ```

   But it seems like this embedded content is exported on the first frame, so my preloader only appears *after* the content .swf is loaded. I'm guessing it's something along these lines. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> But it seems like this embedded content is exported on the first frame

You are absolutely correct, all `Ebmed` do embedding in the first frame by default but mxmlc provides solution by creating two frames swf with preloader in the first frame via the metatag:

```
[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
```

You can find step by step guide here http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=946.

Comment: That post seems to be outdated. I tried everything it suggested to no avail... Is it possible things have changed since then?

Comment: To be more specific, I am able to compile using mxlc, but I get a lot of runtime errors like "Class mx.core::MovieClipLoaderAsset could not be found."

Comment: No, _Frame_ metatag works fine still, I use it in all my projects. May be this link I found just now is more close to the result you need to get http://blog.yoz.sk/2011/01/using-metadata-frame-for-preloader/. What about your error, I seems that some classed doesn't inluded, but mxmlc checks the _Frame_ tag and include all using classes in the second frame as the isn't first frame at all (I'm sure about this by at least 10 projects with this loader technique). Are your project pure AS3 or contains mxml files?

Comment: I tried the other link you gave, but I arrived at the same problem. I have an App.as file which I am placing the [Embed(source="content.swf")] in, and this is what is throwing the error. My guess is that maybe your App.as is the actual main class for your project?